# method to trace function call in C++

Tags: c++, valgrind

I'm using a large software package that doesn't have any consistent method error handling. I see error messages like this:

```
ERROR: stupid message
```

Now, using `grep` etc., I was able to find the function where this message is emitted, i.e.

```
void somefunc(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2, ...){
  // ...
  std::cout << "ERROR: stupid message" << std::endl;
}
```

However, I have difficulties finding out where this function is called in my usecase. If this was an exception or segfault, I could see the stack trace - but like this, I'm a bit lost.

I can't touch the code of `somefunc`, so I guess I'll have to use `valgrind` or something like that to find the offending function call, but I wouldn't know how to do this. I'm using a Linux system and compile my code with `g++`, but I can't  change or recompile the code section containing `somefunc`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Use `cscope` on your codebase.

Comment: you could use a debugger and add a break point.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and setting a breakpoint on where that error is emitted (you can break on data changes if the location is not enough) and then getting a backtrace?

Comment: On linux, I'd just `strace` first... (you might want to `grep` the output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some techniques (tools) to help you:

### Use a debugger

Place a breakpoint at the output statement.
When the breakpoint is reached, print a back trace or view the call stack.

### Generate a call tree

Some documentation tools, like Doxygen, can generate a "caller" and "callee" graph.  You can use these to search for possible execution paths.